# How to handle data fixtures in Symfony when there are non-nullable entity relationships?

Tags: symfony, fixtures

I'm developing an application in Symfony and am yet to setup some data fixtures - I think it'd about time I got round to doing it so setting up a fresh dev copy is faster. :-)

Using my example below, how would I handle setting the 'category' property on my blog to a category? Assuming a ManyToOne relationship with a category entity.

```
$blog1 = new Blog();
$blog1->setTitle('A day with Symfony2');
$blog1->setImage('beach.jpg');
$blog1->setAuthor('dsyph3r');
$manager->persist($blog1);
```

I've gathered from the Symblog tutorial that I include AbstractFixture and the Category entity in my file, but surely the category needs to be created before the blog for this to work? How can I ensure that happens when running my fixtures command?

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [share objects between ordered fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures) — make the categories fixture run before the posts fixture.